# Autofit Cell Size (both rows and columns) after pasting an image

Tags: vba, excel

I have been working on this code where I need to take input of images from my PC, paste them in a certain column, and then resize the cells according to the image size. Following is the code, I am using:

```
Sub BBS()
Dim file As Variant
Dim r As Integer
Dim ID As Integer
 For r = 1 To 6
  ID = Cells(r, 1).Value
  file = "D:\" & ID & ".jpg"
  If Dir(file) = "" Then

  Else
  With ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(file)
    .Left = ActiveSheet.Cells(r, 5).Left
    .Top = ActiveSheet.Cells(r, 5).Top
  End With
  End If
  Next r

Call Resize

End Sub

Sub Resize()

 Worksheets("Sheet1").Columns("A:I").AutoFit
 Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows("1:10").AutoFit
End Sub
```

The images are getting pasted, but I'm not able to adjust the cell size.

Comment: The autofit method only take into account the content of the cells, so it's normal that you can't resize it like this, as pictures are pasted above cells. I would say that the best way would be to get the image size and the resize the column. But I don't know what references you have because I can't seem to find `Pictures` anywhere in my Object browser...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because the picture is not *in* the cell - it has merely been placed in the worksheet at the position of the cell.

Try in in Excel itself (not the VBA window). You are essentially inserting a picture, moving it so that it matches up with the top-left coordinates of a cell, and then trying to AutoFit. (Nothing will happen to the cell).

You can 'fudge' it by setting the size of your pictures using this:

```
Sub BBS()

    Dim file As Variant
    Dim r As Integer
    Dim ID As Integer

    For r = 1 To 6
        ID = Cells(r, 1).Value
        file = "D:\" & ID & ".jpg"
        If Not Dir(file) = "" Then

        With ActiveSheet.
            .AddPicture file, msoFalse, msoTrue, _
             ActiveSheet.Cells(r, 5).Left, ActiveSheet.Cells(r, 5).Top, 100, 100
        End With

        End If
    Next r

    Call Resize

End Sub
```

```
Sub Resize()

    Worksheets("Sheet1").Columns("A:I").ColumnWidth = 18.29
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows("1:10").RowHeight = 100

End Sub
```

Note that the scales used by `.AddPicture` and `ColumnWidth` / `RowHeight` are not the same. You'll have to experiment here.

---

**Updated**

```
Sub BBS()

    Dim r As Integer
    Dim ID As Integer
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Dim objShell As New Shell
    Dim objFolder As Folder
    Dim objFile As ShellFolderItem

    Dim strDimensions As String
    Dim intPos As Integer 'Position of first space in strDimensions
    Dim intWidth As Integer
    Dim intHeight As Integer
    Dim intWidthMax As Integer

    Set objFolder = objShell.Namespace("D:\")

    Set ws = ActiveSheet

    intWidthMax = 0

    For r = 1 To 3
       ID = Cells(r, 1).Value

       Set objFile = objFolder.ParseName(ID & ".jpg")

       strDimensions = objFile.ExtendedProperty("Dimensions")

       intPos = InStr(1, strDimensions, " ", vbTextCompare)

       'These next variables contain the dimensions of the image in pixels.
       intWidth = CInt(Mid(strDimensions, 2, intPos - 2))
       intHeight = CInt(Mid(strDimensions, intPos + 3, Len(strDimensions) - intPos - 3))

       With ActiveSheet.Shapes
          'Here we treat the dimension values (which are actually in pixels) as points.
          'The conversions depend on your DPI, so you could play around with a scaling
          'factor here.
          .AddPicture objFile.Path, msoFalse, msoTrue, ActiveSheet.Cells(r, 5).Left, _
           ActiveSheet.Cells(r, 5).Top, intWidth, intHeight
        End With

       'RowHeight is done in points, so it will match the height of your images.
       ws.Rows(r).RowHeight = intHeight

       If intWidth > intWidthMax Then intWidthMax = intWidth

   Next r

    'Set column width to widest image width.
    'Width points are different from height points.
    '5.29 as a conversion works for me (and my DPI).
    ws.Columns(5).ColumnWidth = intWidthMax / 5.29

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the information. Would it be possible that I first let vba obtain the image size and then set the cell size accordingly?